Docker image size is coming up to 9.75 G for Ubuntu with Python packages
Here is my Dockerfile. The problem is that the Image size is 9.75gb
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Avoid warnings by switching to noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt update && apt   && ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata

# Install python and opencv
RUN apt install python3 python3-venv python3-pip python3-opencv -y

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /App

# Copy the local directory contents to the container
COPY . .
# Install the Python dependencies
RUN pip3 install opencv-python matplotlib numpy Pillow torch torchvision tqdm pyyaml requests pandas seaborn flask flask_cors scipy --break-system-packages


# Revert back to the dialog on apt operations
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=dialog

EXPOSE 5000
# Run the application
CMD ["python3", "./app.py"]

I need to install all the following python packages for a model server. I know these packages can be large but 9gbs is crazy... Can anyone help me reduce the size of the image?
Update: I switched to python image and now it takes up 5.41gb - which reduced significantly from the original size - but still too large.
FROM python:3.6

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /App

# Copy the local directory contents to the container
COPY . .
# Install the Python dependencies
RUN pip3 install opencv-python --verbose
RUN pip3 install opencv-python matplotlib numpy Pillow torch torchvision tqdm pyyaml requests pandas seaborn flask flask_cors scipy
EXPOSE 5000
# Run the application
CMD ["python", "./app.py"]


all the following python packages <- EOL while scanning for packages literals

Why start with Ubuntu? Why not start with a (smaller) python image?

What is in the local directory? Why do you install venv when you have a Docker container for sandboxing?

How large is the local directory (how much space does COPY . . require)?  Other questions I've seen suggest PyTorch on its own is extremely large (this one suggests it's ~3 GB on its own).  Any suggestions like changing the base image or removing APT cache files will just be noise against this.

The local directory is only about 155mb. I updated the Dockerfile to run from python and it reduced to 5.41gb - which is significant. But still large

Add --no-cache-dir to pip3 install to not cache any downloaded packages. That way I reduced the image to ~3.27GB (without the app copying):
FROM python:3.6

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /App

# Copy the local directory contents to the container
COPY . .
# Install the Python dependencies - note the --no-cache-dir
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir opencv-python matplotlib numpy Pillow torch torchvision tqdm pyyaml requests pandas seaborn flask flask_cors scipy
EXPOSE 5000

# Run the application
CMD ["python", "./app.py"]


Thanks! I used them and it reduced to 3.43gbs

This is an amazing tool to better understand which layers of your Docker image increases the image size:
https://github.com/wagoodman/dive
One suggestion to trim some low-hanging-fruit is to remove temporary and cached files. E.g. apt install can create files which would speed up subsequent installs, which bloat that layer.
How to address tools creating unnecessary temporary files is a bit tool-specific, but with apt you can avoid most of it like so:
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python3 python3-venv python3-pip python3-opencv -y && apt-get clean


I used the tool and the results shows that 8gbs are coming from this command
RUN pip3 install opencv-python matplotlib numpy Pillow torch torchvision tqdm pyyaml requests pandas seaborn flask flask_cors scipy --break-system-packages
Unfortunately I can't remove any of them

BTW: https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#here-documents. If you want things in one image layer, you can still well spread the multiple commands over multiple lines without a mess of backslashes connecting them.

@UlrichEckhardt Fair enough, although would go with multi-line instead, you can just use a \ to continue on the next line. :) (Doesn't render properly in comments, but add a newline after every slash.)
RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y openssl \
  && apt-get clean

